# Rotating axis labels in lattice() package - R

Tags: r, package

I case of built-in R plotting function I can change orientation of axis labels with `las` parameter, which takes values : `{0, 1, 2, 3}`. How to achive the same with plotting functions from `lattice()` ? 
I don't see any difference between :

```
set.seed(22342317);levelplot(matrix(runif(100),10,10),las=0)
set.seed(22342317);levelplot(matrix(runif(100),10,10),las=1)
set.seed(22342317);levelplot(matrix(runif(100),10,10),las=2)
set.seed(22342317);levelplot(matrix(runif(100),10,10),las=3)
```

I've tried also with `las` as parameter of `par()`, but output is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this using `rot` instead of `las`

```
levelplot(matrix(runif(100),10,10), scales=list(y=list(rot=45), x=list(rot=45)))
```